# Can a website solely rely on Facebook Connect to log user in without having a users table?

Tags: facebook

I was thinking that for Facebook Connect, can we rely solely on using it to log users in, and show "Log in / Sign up" vs "Logged in as [Michael] / Log out" and not needing to handle users on the web server (such as using Ruby on Rails) so there is no users table, no authentication system at all, but just let Facebook handle everything?

But as it turned out, looks like it is not so feasible?  Because somehow, we still need to use the user_id to save in some of our records in the DB, such as, when a user add an item to a "Save to list", or post a message, we still need to use the user_id in that row of the `user_item_junction_table` or `messages` table.  We can use Javascript so that the POST will actually contain the Facebook user_id, by using Facebook's Javascript SDK and just add the user_id to the form's hidden variable...  but is it a workable solution or is it recommended?

I see a typical website having its own authentication, and then just letting the Facebook account be "one of their users"... so each Facebook user still has a user record in the legacy system.

Answer (score 0):

For our FB Connect application, we are using our own user record that is linked up to the Facebook user ID.  You could always maintain your own user table and have Facebook user ID be the unique identifier, but that locks you in to FB Connect.  Using a separate, internal user ID will allow you to link other type of shared login scheme (e.g., OpenID) to your user accounts.